# Jest - Mocking a function that in turn has a method defined on it

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am converting some old tests to use Jest, and I have a function that is called `Services.Transactions.get`. Normally you pass it a callback to process the data returned from a remote API. In my tests I'm mocking it, using

```
jest.spyOn(Services.Transactions, 'get').mockImplementation((callback) => { callback(someJsObject); });
```

So far so good.

Now the problem is that it in turn has a method `Services.Transactions.get.watch`. The module I'm testing uses both of these functions. Once I mock the first above, I can't mock the watcher method. I'm told `Services.Transactions.get.watch` is not a function.

I've tried:

- Defining a function with an empty watch method defined on it, and using it as the implementation for get.
- Trying to also replace the watch method using mockImplementation calls

None of the above worked. The file services is coming from is not an ES6 module so doing a module-level mock is something I'd prefer to avoid. Do I have any other options?

Comment: so `get` is a function with with methods attached on it? Have you tried `Services.Transactions.get, 'watch')` before setting the spy on get?

Comment: @JuanMendes Your understanding is correct. As for the suggestion, I had tried that, it didn't work. user268396's answer below worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the straightforward approach:

```
const mock = jest.spyOn(Services.Transactions, 'get');
mock.watch = jest.fn();
mock.mockImplementation(...);
```